# Span class not changing anything

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change everything in the span class "Intro" to have these settings:

```
span.Intro{  
display: inline-block;
margin-left:0px;
font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
 line-height: 0px;
 height: 25px;
 color: grey; 
 list-style:square; 
 font-size: 150%;
 padding-left: 0px;}
```

An example of what line I'm trying to do this on:

`<span class ="Intro" <ul><li><b>History</b></li></ul></span>`

this previously worked but I opened my file today and it does not?
The outcome is currently just a normal pre formatted circle bold bullet point, any help?

EDIT: Solved, thanks for all your help

Comment: The posted markup is invalid, the closing angle-brace is missed. Besides, `<span>` is an inline wrapper, it is not designed to wrap block-level elements such as lists.

Comment: @Corey Put a `*` after `span.Intro` in your stylesheet (CSS). It should look like this: `span.Intro *`

Comment: your opening span tag doesn't have closing brace buddy :)

Comment: I've closed the <span> and yet still no result?

Comment: If correcting the markup didn't make change, there may be some other styles overriding yours within the stylesheet.

Comment: For me on Chrome the style on the li is overriding the span. I recommend putting the Intro class on your `li` rather than a superfluous span tag and change your css to `li.Intro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
<span class ="Intro" <ul><li><b>History</b></li></ul></span>
```

Need:

```
<span class ="Intro" ><ul><li><b>History</b></li></ul></span>
```

Comment: Just made the change and it still doesn't change the text?

Comment: Try to open in your browser Inspect element and you will see what problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Check `<span class="Intro">`And remember **span** is inline element and **ul** is block element. You should not nest a block element in an inline element. You can use **span** inside **ul** but don't use **ul** inside **span**

See, for instance,http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp
 or 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/aa011000a.htm

Answer (score 0):

HTML Markup

```
<span class ="Intro"><ul><li>History></li></ul></span>
```

CSS style

```
span.Intro ul li{  
    margin-left:0px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 0px;
    color: grey; 
    list-style:square; 
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "span.Intro" with "span.Intro ul" in your css file.